# underlined letter shortcut in Word doesn't work

Tags: microsoft-word, keyboard-shortcuts

The underlined letter shortcut which is present in many menus in MS Word (where you can press a the underlined letter to open that option, see [answers.microsoft.com](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/what-do-the-underlined-letters-mean/06c52e0a-9c27-4f88-9eca-28794740f631#:%7E:text=It%20means%20you%20can%20press,keyboard%20to%20open%20the%20object.&text=Was%20this%20reply%20helpful%3F&text=these%20are%20the%20letters%20used%20for%20the%20keyboard%20shortcut)), doesn't work on my computer (Windows 10, Word 2019). Although it works in Windows menus. How can it be fixed?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Uninstalling Office, restart and install Office again.  You may try to remake Normal.dot

Comment: Which particular menu shortcut? Does it work in Word if you start it in safe mode? https://support.office.com/article/dedf944a-5f4b-4afb-a453-528af4f7ac72

Comment: @CharlesKenyon In safe mode it works properly.

Comment: Next step is to find and rename your Normal.dotm template with Word closed. https://addbalance.com/word/normaltemplate.htm#Find If it works then, let Word regenerate the normal template.

Comment: @CharlesKenyon They say that by renaming it the changes and macros can be recovered,  but they don't say how. Have info. about that?

Comment: First, did renaming it help? If it does not, you can simply rename back.

Comment: @CharlesKenyon Thanks for your support. Please see my answer. Sorry for being wrong about safe mode, I didn't suspect that it was because of the languages.

Answer (score 1):

It's apparently a bug that's happening when using right-to-left languages. I found that it happens with many computers, which means that it's probably happening with all of them. And safe mode doesn't help for that. It doesn't happen in all menus, it only happens in such dialog boxes that need to be closed manually (for example: find and replace, page setup, paragraph), but not in menus that disappear with a click outside of the menu (like the right click menu, and drop-down menus). I guess this needs Microsoft's attention, but meanwhile we can change to a left-to-right keyboard (press windows+space) right before using the underlined letter shortcut (and it will work even if the whole document is in right-to-left).

Comment: See my article on how to communicate wishes / bugs to Microsoft on the Microsoft answers site. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/giving-feedback-on-microsoft-word-or-other/8df81a9b-84aa-46ef-bf88-24fb7fec96ba?tm=1682959639719